# Cannot set device ring parameters: Operation not supported

Tags: linux, networking, yocto, ethernet

I am using a Yocto Linux System

```
ID="poky"
NAME="Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro)"
VERSION="3.0.4 (zeus)"
VERSION_ID="3.0.4"
PRETTY_NAME="Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro) 3.0.4 (zeus)"
```

With this kernel `5.4.47-rt28`

I am using a TQ MBLS1028A-IND with this network card "Ethernet controller: Freescale Semiconductor Inc Device e100"

With the ethtool of the interface I get the following info

```
ethtool eno0
Settings for eno0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                         1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 3
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Link detected: yes
```

When I try to run the following command to increase the ring buffer

```
# ethtool -G eno0 rx 4096
```

I get the following error

```
Cannot set device ring parameters: Operation not supported
```

In this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/958291/cannot-set-device-ring-parameters-operation-not-supported) it was say that I can increase it with by editing one line of this file

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno0
```

But I dont have that file

Do you have hint of how I can do to increase the ring parameter?

Another output that can be of help

```
# ethtool -g eno0
Ring parameters for eno0:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:     0
RX Mini:    0
RX Jumbo:   0
TX:     0
Current hardware settings:
RX:     512
RX Mini:    0
RX Jumbo:   0
TX:     256
```